# What is MVC and what are the advantages of it?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

I found [What are mvp and mvc and what is the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference) but it didn't really answer this question.

I've recently started using MVC because it's part of the framework that myself and my work-partner are going to use. We chose it because it looked easy and separated process from display, are there advantages besides this that we don't know about and could be missing out on?

**Pros**

1. Display and Processing are seperated

**Cons**

1. None so far

Answer (score 46, accepted):

MVC is the separation of **m**odel, **v**iew and **c**ontroller — nothing more, nothing less. It's simply a paradigm; an ideal that you should have in the back of your mind when designing classes. Avoid mixing code from the three categories into one class.

For example, while a table grid *view* should obviously present data once shown, it should not have code on where to retrieve the data from, or what its native structure (the *model*) is like. Likewise, while it may have a function to sum up a column, the actual summing is supposed to happen in the *controller*.

A 'save file' dialog (*view*) ultimately passes the path, once picked by the user, on to the *controller*, which then asks the *model* for the data, and does the actual saving.

This separation of responsibilities allows flexibility down the road. For example, because the view doesn't care about the underlying model, supporting multiple file formats is easier: just add a model subclass for each.

Answer (score 14):

Separation of concerns is the biggy.

Being able to tease these components apart makes the code easier to re-use and independently test. If you don't actually know what MVC is, be careful about trying to understand people's opinions as there is still some contention about what the "Model" is (whether it is the business objects/DataSets/DataTables or if it represents the underlying service layer).

I've seen all sorts of implementations that call themselves MVC but aren't exactly and as the comments in [Jeff's article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001112.html) show MVC is a contentious point that I don't think developers will ever fully agree upon.

A good round up of all of the different MVC types is available [here](http://aspiringcraftsman.com/2007/08/25/interactive-application-architecture/).

Comment: +1 your reference are really awesome especially the different MVCs.

Answer (score 7):

Jeff has a [post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001112.html) about it, otherwise I found some useful documents on Apple's website, in Cocoa tutorials ([this one](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/chapter_5_section_4.html) for example).

Answer (score 3):

I think another benefit of using the MVC pattern is that it opens up the doors to other *approaches* to the design, such as MVP/Presenter first and the many other MV* patterns.

Without this fundamental segregation of the design "components" the adoption of these techniques would be much more difficult.

I think it helps to make your code even more interface-based.. Not only within the individual project, but you can almost start to develop common "views" which mean you can template lot more of the "grunt" code used in your applications. For example, a very abstract "data view" which simply takes a bunch of data and throws it to a common grid layout.

#### Edit:

If I remember correctly, [this is a pretty good podcast on MV* patterns](http://www.polymorphicpodcast.com/shows/mv-patterns/) (listened to it a while ago!)

Answer (score 2):

MVC is just a general design pattern that, in the context of lean web app development, makes it easy for the developer to keep the HTML markup in an app’s presentation layer (the view) separate from the methods that receive and handle client requests (the controllers) and the data representations that are returned within the view (the models). It’s all about separation of concerns, that is, keeping code that serves one functional purpose (e.g. handling client requests) sequestered from code that serves an entirely different functional purpose (e.g. representing data).

It’s the same principle for why anybody who’s spent more than 5 min trying to build a website can appreciate the need to keep your HTML markup, JavaScript, and CSS in separate files: If you just dump all of your code into a single file, you end up with spaghetti that’s virtually un-editable later on.

**Since you asked for possible "cons":** I’m no authority on software architecture design, but based on my experience developing in MVC, I think it’s also important to point out that following a strict, no-frills MVC design pattern is most useful for 1) lightweight web apps, or 2) as the UI layer of a larger enterprise app. I’m surprised this specification isn’t  talked about more, because MVC contains no explicit definitions for your business logic, domain models, or really anything in the data access layer of your app. When I started developing in ASP.NET MVC (i.e. before I knew other software architectures even existed), I would end up with very bloated controllers or even view models chock full of business logic that, had I been working on enterprise applications, would have made it difficult for other devs who were unfamiliar with my code to modify (i.e. more spaghetti).

Answer (score 1):

One con I can think of is if you need really fast access to your data in your view (for example, game animation data like bone positions.) It is very inefficient to keep a layer of separation in this case.

Otherwise, for most other applications which are more data driven than graphics driven, it seems like a logical way to drive a UI.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the stackoverflow podcasts you can hear Jeff (and Geoff?) discuss its greatness.  https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/08/podcast-17/.  But remember that using these separate layers means things are easier in the future--and harder now.  And layers *can* make things slower.  And you may not need them.  But don't let that stop you from learning what it is--when building big, robust, long-lived systems, it's invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

It separates Model and View controlled by a Controller, 
As far as Model is concerned, Your Models has to follow OO architecture, future enhancements and other maintenance of the code base should be very easy and the code base should be reusable.

Same model can have any no.of views e.g) same info can be shown in as different graphical views.
Same view can have different no.of models e.g) different detailed can be shown as a single graph say as a bar graph.
This is what is re-usability of both View and Model.

Enhancements in views and other support of new technologies for building the view can be implemented easily.

Guy who is working on view dose not need to know about the underlying Model code base and its architecture, vise versa for the model.

Answer (score 1):

One of the major advantages of MVC which has not mentioned here is that MVC provides RESTful urls which enables SEO. When you name your Controllers and Actions wisely, it makes it easier for search engines to find your site if they only take a look at your site Urls. For example you have a car sale website and a page which displays available Lamborghini Veneno cars, instead of having *www.MyCarSale.com/product/6548* referring to the page you can choose *www.MyCarSale.com/SportCar/Lamborghini-Veneno* url for SEO purpose.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114186/922713) is a good answer to MVC Advantages and [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-create-an-seo-friendly-url-structure--webdesign-9569) is an article How to create a SEO friendly Url.

Answer (score 0):

Main advantage of MVC architecture is differentiating the layers of a project in Model,View and Controller for the Re-usability of code, easy to maintain code and maintenance. The best thing is the developer feels good to add some code in between the project maintenance.

Here you can see the some more points on [Main Advantages of MVC Architecture](http://javabynataraj.blogspot.in/2009/05/14-advantages-of-mvc-arch.html).

Answer (score 0):

![mvc architecture][1]

Model–view–controller (MVC) is a software architectural pattern for implementing user interfaces. It divides a given software application into three interconnected parts, so as to separate internal representations of information from the ways that information is presented to or accepted from the user.