# page is not redirect

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Exception in JSP: /views/header.jsp:14

```
11:         <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>">Home</a> | 
12:         <% String username=(String)session.getAttribute("formdata");
13:         String admin="admin";
14:         if(username.equals(" ")){
15:             
16:             String logout="http://localhost:8080/NewsBank/logout.do";
17:             response.sendRedirect(logout);
```

Stacktrace:

```
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:451)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:321)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:257)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:801)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.views.addStory_jsp._jspService(addStory_jsp.java:93)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:321)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:257)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:801)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

Comment: in this code i dont get redirect to asking page..ie logout page

Comment: perhaps you should be null checking the username variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`username` seems `null` to me.

Check for nullity

```
if(username != null || "".equals(userName)){
//your code
}
```

---

**Suggestions:**

- We have [Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) for this (authentication check) purpose why spoiling jsp ?
- [Avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)  writing javacode on JSP

---

**See Also**

- [Why business logic should be moved out of JSP ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818101/why-business-logic-should-be-moved-out-of-jsp/5818154#5818154)
- [JSP Coding Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html)

Comment: +1 not only for the right answer, but also for the good way. Good.

Comment: i have 3 diffrent cases in the header page ..ie 1)if(username.isEmpty()){  //redirect to index page  }          2)else if(username.equals(admin)){ //redirect to admin page  }       3)else if(username!=admin && username!=""){//redirect to all user page}

Comment: 1. check for nullity 2. you can compare string using `equals()` not using `==` 3. read out *Suggestions* section

Comment: means in case of username==null then it must have redirect to index page......... to which it is not redirect now

Comment: `username == null` if this returns true it says that you don't have username set in session so it should go to login page I guess

Comment: yes...but how redirect to that page i use response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()); in this block but not working gives above error.... i used index.jsp, index.do, logout.do almost everything in paramaeter of the sendRedirect

Comment: yes Jigar...you r true...but i did not getting to it in right way or u  have to say some more abt it...actully i used one line before for assigning a value of the code in to a variable so that it went to nullPointerExecption everytime.....it did not came to if(){} block...well thank you very much jigar....i got solution