# How to pass a parameter to previous page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working on a JSP project.  I have a page that calls another JSP.

Now the problem is, how to pass or use a variable in the called JSP page in its calling page?

Comment: I don't get it. The previous page is not accessed anymore, so you don't get to execute any code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the variable in the HTTPSession or ServletContext object.

And in the calling JSP page, use or check session attribute for the variable.

`session.setAttribute(objectId, Object);` to set the variable.

`session.getAttribute(objectId);` to get the variable.

Comment: also use `session.removeAttribute(objectId);` after the variable is not needed.

Comment: @Ankit: You must go for session scope when needed, not for every other thing. That might be the reason you got downvoted. But I'm not sure, that was just my idea. And of course, what you suggested is indeed a possibility.

Comment: @Adeel : Yes you are but I answered keeping in mind that he can also use that varable in all the jsp pages where needed. And as harry Joy mentioned in comment it can be removed.  But your point is also right.

Comment: @Ankit: Give a man a fish and he will eat for the day. Teach a man to fish and he will eat for life.

Answer (score 1):

Your design should be

- take one input param on page1.jsp
- post it to some servlet , process it there, forward request to page1 jsp and pass param taken from page 1 as attribute

**See Also**

- [why-business-logic-should-be-moved-out-of-jsp ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818101/why-business-logic-should-be-moved-out-of-jsp/)

Answer (score 1):

> I have a page that calls another jsp
>   page

The problem lies here in this sentence.

Try to follow [**MVC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Use `JSP` just for rendering the **View**, and `Servlet` as a **Controller**.

Here, [simple.souther.us](http://simple.souther.us/), you find simple and awesome tutorials for newbies.