# Error while importing in jsp page

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

i want to perform some test by using Json . I am using google app engine for development . I want to know how to import json lib and how i can import in jsp page . 
The work i have done so far can be seen in picture[image]

i am not sure that i have added jar file correctly or not it is marked with red . 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh right Gson is the Google JSON library - you'll need to import it in your JSP.  Make sure it's on the Build Path for your project for example

```
<%@ page import="com.google.gson.Gson" %>
```

Comment: perfect but now its there is red line under com

Comment: The compiler error (if you hover over the red line) should tell you more.

Comment: it saying "package com.google.gson.Gson dosent exit " . I think its importing problem . now i have also added as properties -> build -> packages -> add jar . But still no hope

Comment: yes i'm not much of a netbeans user, but you should right click the project > Properties > Libraries > Compile > Add Library.  Make sure you have added the google gson library...

Answer (score 1):

You need to import them on jsp as well, the same way you have imported `List`

**See Also**

- [why-business-logic-should-be-moved-out-of-jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818101/why-business-logic-should-be-moved-out-of-jsp)

Comment: for importing i have done done this <%@ page import="com.google.gson.Gson" %>and as it can be seen in the picture how i have added jar file but still its saying "com.google.gson.Gson doesnot not exit "

Comment: ignore that error try to build and deploy. probably just a ide's issue.

Comment: After deploying An error occurred at line: -1 in the generated java file
    [javac] C:\DOCUME~1\test\LOCALS~1\Temp\Jetty_localhost_8080_web____.7ij05v\jsp\org\apache\jsp\Mediasense_jsp.java:10: package com.google.gson does not exist
    [javac] import com.google.gson.Gson;
    [javac]                       ^

Comment: Check for the jar , is it there in WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: how can i add into  WEB-INF/lib as i am using netbeans .In  WEB-INF there is no lib folder . i have added into libraries as in the picture . Is it wrong ?