# to dynamically generate a web page, which is better?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I heard that jsp is anyway be convevrted to servlet, so is it better to directly use servlets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**

Use jsp for view only.

Use Servlet for controller only.

Use service layer to do processing ..etc..

**See Also**

- [why-business-logic-should-be-moved-out-of-jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818101/why-business-logic-should-be-moved-out-of-jsp)

Answer (score 1):

with jsp it is simpler to make good design with html and css, because in servlets you will use out.println to output every line of html code(e.g. `out.println("<head>...</head>")`)