# Passing values from Server through JSP to javascript functions

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a serious problem.

Firstly, I am trying to retrieve values from my database by individual scripts on my JSP pages. Here is part of the code:

---

```
<%String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

Connection con=null;

ResultSet rst=null;`

Statement stmt=null;

try{

String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MajorProjectDB?user=cdsadmin2&password=enjoyit";

con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);

stmt=con.createStatement();

}
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

String name= request.getRemoteUser();

rst=stmt.executeQuery("select verifycode from Staff where name='"+name+"'");
%>

<%
int no=1;`
while(rst.next()){

%>

<%=no%>

<%=rst.getString("VERIFYCODE")%>

<%String code= request.getParameter("code"); %>

<% } %>
```

---

In this code I am storing a string from **VERIFYCODE** column in my Staff table. 
I will be able to compare it with the user input within the form by using a `getparameter`.

HOWEVER, the comparison should be done with `onClick` function, but due to the fact that it is running as an individual script, it cannot be attached to the `onClick` function.

Now I am trying to insert an SQL statement in the following javascript in my JSP page:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function verifyCode(){ 

// a SELECT sql statement which gets String from database

//comparison between String retrieved from database and user input

if{

  }

else{

}

}

</script>
```

---

May I know if anyone has any solution? Or is there a easier method of doing it?
Thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try using [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for making a request to a JSP page for data and then return the data as a response to that request. Try googling abou **AJAX**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server converts jsp to HTML and sends to client and client gets only HTML javascript are executed on client side.

For your case you can use [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org), to call java method from server from the javascript

**See Also**

- [why-business-logic-should-be-moved-out-of-jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818101/why-business-logic-should-be-moved-out-of-jsp)

Answer (score 0):

JSP is server side, javascript is client side !

Your javascript cannot insert anything into a DB its client side

some tips:
Throw away scriptlets and use proper seperation of view logic and business logic.