# How to send multiple values of a table from HashMap in java to jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

I want to send multiple values from a table from a database from hashmap in java tp a jsp file.this is what i have done so far

```
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM seeding where scheme = '"+user+"' "); 
    HashMap<String, String> verify = new HashMap<String, String>();
    while (rs.next())
    {
    verify.put("beneficiaryID",rs.getString("beneficiaryID"));
    verify.put("scheme", rs.getString("scheme"));
    verify.put("aadhaar",rs.getString("aadhaar"));
    verify.put("name",rs.getString("name"));
    }
    request.setAttribute("verify", verify);
```

jsp >>

```
<%
HashMap<String, String> verify = (HashMap<String, String>) 
request.getAttribute("verify");
for (String key : verify.keySet())  
{ 
out.print(verify.get("aadhaar"));
out.print(verify.get("scheme"));
out.print(verify.get("beneficiaryID")+"$"+verify.get("name"));
}
```

But this only gives the last Row of the table not all the results !!
What needs to be changed ?
thanks

Comment: It means code shouldnt be dumped into a JSP page in scriptlet form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
HashMap<String, String> verify = new HashMap<String, String>();
while (rs.next())
{
    verify.put("beneficiaryID",rs.getString("beneficiaryID"));
    verify.put("scheme", rs.getString("scheme"));
    verify.put("aadhaar",rs.getString("aadhaar"));
    verify.put("name",rs.getString("name"));
}
```

Each time through the loop, which is for each row in the database or each result set row, you put the same entries in the `Map` with new values.

Each row overwrites the previous one.

You can't get them out in the JSP since you overwrote all but the last one.

There are several solutions. I would create a POJO class with the 4 properties and put each row result in a list. But, lets use your map idea:

```
List results = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
while (rs.next())
{
    Map<String, String> verify = new HashMap<String, String>();
    verify.put("beneficiaryID",rs.getString("beneficiaryID"));
    verify.put("scheme", rs.getString("scheme"));
    verify.put("aadhaar",rs.getString("aadhaar"));
    verify.put("name",rs.getString("name"));
    results.add(verify);
}
 request.setAttribute("verify", results);
```

Now you have to change up the JSP a bit (ugly java code that it has in it):

```
<%
List<Map<String, String>> results = (List<Map<String, String>>)request.getAttribute("verify");
for (Map<String, String> verify: results) {
{ 
    out.print(verify.get("aadhaar"));
    out.print(verify.get("scheme"));
    out.print(verify.get("beneficiaryID")+"$"+verify.get("name"));
}
%>
```

Comment: ok i got what the problem is but i dont know how to fix that. What is the alternate ! ?

Answer (score 0):

> What needs to be changed ?

Code! data structure should be a Map of `beneficiaryId` - > `BeneficiaryModel` ( a class representing `Beneficiary` model

`Map` is the structure of unique keys to values

Also [don't use java code in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818101/why-business-logic-should-be-moved-out-of-jsp/5818154#5818154)

Comment: Are you specifying multimap ?

Comment: I'd contend a list of `BeneficiaryModel` would probably be a better fit to what he sounds like he wants.  I don't think there should be any Maps involved in this at all.