# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP.

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 176 in the jsp file: /encrypted.jsp
gn cannot be resolved

173:     <input type="text" name="itt"  value=""  />
174:         </label><br><br><br><br>
175:            <label><b>Generated Key-</b>
176:             <input type="text" name="Gnkey" value="<%=gn%>"/>
177:         </label>
178:  </td>
```

the gn variable is used to store a output from a function

```
<%
String gn = generateKey(SelectedIndex, key, itt);
%>
```

how to resolve this error?

Comment: where is `gn` variable defined and initialized? It should be before html tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in `pageContext`

```
<%
  pageContext.setAttribute("gn", gn);
%>
```

and then access it like `${gn}`

**or**

change

```
<%
String gn = generateKey(SelectedIndex, key, itt);
%>
```

to

```
<!%
String gn = generateKey(SelectedIndex, key, itt);
%>
```

---

**Also See**

- [why business logic should be moved out of JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818101/why-business-logic-should-be-moved-out-of-jsp)

Comment: error in writing `pageContext.setAttribute("gn", gn);`  showing, cannot find the symbol gn.

Comment: you do it in the same scope as `String gn = generateKey(SelectedIndex, key, itt);`

Comment: not working this. but first decelerating String gn in `<%! String gn; %>` helped. now recognized at every place i used.