# body onload is not able to trigger action url in html form

Tags: html, servlets, onload

I am using the onload method in the form like below in one of my servlet:

```
out.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\"       \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\"> \n");
out.write("<html><body onload=\"document.forms[0].submit()\">\n");
out.write("<form method=\"POST\" action=\"http://ipaddress:8085/internal/Logout\">\n");
out.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"groupId\" value=\"" + groupId
        + "\"/>\n");
out.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"userName\" value=\""
        + userName + "\"/>\n");
out.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"idpServer\" value=\""
        + idpServer + "\"/>\n");
out.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sessionId\" value=\""
        + sessionId + "\"/>\n");
out.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"targetPage\" value=\""
        + targetPageURL + "\"/>\n");

out.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"locale\" value=\""
        + locale + "\"/>\n");
out.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"logoutPage\" value=\""
        + logoutPage + "\"/>\n");

out.write("</form>\n</body>\n</html>\n");
```

After the above code i have one more line which is like

deleteExpiredSession(sessionId);

In the first code block we have 'onload' method which will automatically submits the form to action url but in my case it is not happening
the control is going to some other servlet.

- In debug mode the code executing along with the second part of code(deleteExpiredSession(sessionId);), I think the second part should
  not be executed because the above code is having onload.
  Earlier it was working fine but suddenly it is stopped working. I think recently we migrated to tomcat6 - tomcat7. Is this the reason?
  Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: separate view and controller first, this is a challenge to maintain this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818101/why-business-logic-should-be-moved-out-of-jsp

Comment: yes that's right @JigarJoshi, I will separate it, i do not know why it is not able to submit the form to action url

Comment: The URL that you submit your post to is not valid (`http://ipaddress:port/internal/Logout`)

Comment: The url is correct, please see edited post.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your application and I found out the problem is about your action address and id is not valid. You doesn't put `port` word after `:` in your URL. Change it to following code and it will work:

```
<form method="get" action="http://ipaddress:8080/internal/Logout" >
 ...
```

I replaced `8080` with `port`.

Comment: For the sake of example i have put that word, Please see above my edited post

Comment: @User: What about the stars around the onload, `**onload**`?

Comment: that i did for make it bold actually.

Comment: I am using firefox 24.0

Comment: I tested it on Firefox 34.0 and Chromium. Right click on page and select `View Page Source` and copy the content to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67977/discussion-between-user-and-ali-sepehri-kh).

Comment: No Ali, Still the problem is there.