# JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

While migrating Sun Tomcat 5.5 to Tomcat 7 found the next error when trying to access login page

```
Jan 21, 2015 8:37:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
```

An error occurred at line: 62 in the jsp file: /nextagBase.jsp The final local variable request cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment

```
request = HTTPRequest.getRequest(request);
```

I got solution for this problem this was mainly bcz use of single qoutes inside single quotes in JSP and tomcat 7 doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`request` is an implicit final Object reference in jsp](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnaij/index.html), and you are trying to re-assign it which is not valid,

Rename the variable or [better don't write Java on view template like JSP - use JSTL instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818101/why-business-logic-should-be-moved-out-of-jsp)

Comment: thanks commented this line 
request = HTTPRequest.getRequest(request); now its working. :)

Answer (score 0):

check the argument passed to getRequest(). call method without passing arguments.

```
request = HTTPRequest.getRequest();
```