# MVC tutorials for MVP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvp

I'm new to MVP .

can I use tutorials created for asp.net MVC to learn MVP pattern foundations and basics? 
or differences are too much ?

Comment: With source code to practice , Unit Tests also incuded to explain its benefits - http://www.advertisingmarket.co.uk/MVPPattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 patterns are pretty different. The MVP pattern could be used with classic WebForms whereas ASP.NET MVC already integrates lots of the MVC pattern's parts in the framework itself. The separation of concerns is already present. If you want to use MVP with classic WebForms you will have much more work because the pattern is non-existent in the framework.

Comment: thanx , I've read about MVP concepts and definitions . but I have problem with how to for example redirect a user to another page or in wich layer ? where to implement validation ? in fact how to implement MVP to real projects . there are not enough good tutorials for MVP as far as I searched

Comment: I know this is old but just to complete. Your page (view) is doing the redirect as it has acces to the HttpContext. Your Presenter should not access the HttpContext directly. You page (view) derives from an interface i.e: IView which can have a Redirect method taking a URI as a parameter. Your page (View) then implements Redirect. Thus when the Presenter calls `MyView.Redirect(MyUri)` it is the Page (View) that will do the redirect and the presenter only sends the location to it. That also makes testing your presenter so much easier as you can mock your own view and do not rely on httpContext.

Comment: To clarify, your Presenter at the time of execution has access to the HttpContext but when you write unit tests against your presenter you will get `Object not initialized` error as the unit test framework won't be initializing the httpcontext. As the HttpContext is a sealed class not inheriting from any interface you can't mock/fake it. You are better of to ensure your httpContext is only accessed from the view (your page) itself and exposes access to the functionality to the presenter through the IView interface, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**MVC** is good for plain server side scripting. In MVC developers always try to keep the controller very lean. Mainly controller is for just selecting the appropriate model and reflect on the view. But in today's web applications the View part has radically changed and became complex enough to produce a big, fat and messy controller. So now we need a new place to put the user interface's complex control logic. Here the **P** of **MVP** comes in that is the presenter. So presenters are responsible for controlling the logic for a particular user interface component. Don't worry the controller is still here, named as **Application Controller**. Which ultimately responsible for switching between comparatively larger application components. So **MVP** can also be said **MVPC(!!)**. BTW this was my way of understanding MVP and obviously not any ground rule. But Google has some very cool documentations on MVP.