# MVC in c# win. form application

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

I 'am building a small windows form application.

I have **a View** - a simple form that has some functionality in it.
**a Controller** - a class that will react to loading, saving, getting data from the model and prepare it form the view etc.
**a Model** - a class that will get and save data to DB or file.

The controller is creating  a form instance an run it, and creating a model instance when needed.

I wonder about how to react in the controller to the view events.
Should I register to the view events (buttons click, combo change etc.) ?
This will make the form controls visible outside the form?

**Maybe I have a mistake in the design?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you take a look at this SO post
[using MVC MVP patterns in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219882/using-mvc-mvp-patterns-in-winforms)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has created a framework for Win Forms MVC applications, the Composite UI Application framework.

http://www.codeplex.com/smartclient

It is probably overkill for a small project, but you could look at it and get some ideas.

Comment: Neat, I haven't seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

If you google MVP (Model-View-Presenter) you'll find info on how to implement a seperation of concerns pattern in a Windows form application.