# What is the difference between MVP and MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, mvp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are MVP and MVC and what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference)

I don't see any difference between MVP and MVC software architectures (MVC where controller implements mediator pattern), other than the name by which you call the mediator (presenter vs controller)

Can someone provide a clear explanation?

I care because I have a reasonable understanding of MVC via cocoa and I'm wondering how that knowledge will have to grow to understand MPF/C#/.NET

Comment: not using google to search is one thing, but not using SO's search is just sad... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=difference+between+MVP+and+MVC

Comment: Actually I got a bunch of lousy google hits and the 3 so articles I found were written and answered by people who obviously did not have an understanding of the subject. Thanks for link

Answer (score 0):

Darin's provided a good link.  I'd say there are a couple key differences, but a lot of similarity.  MVP's view is even simpler than MVVC's - it doesn't know about the model.  That makes it easier to get everything covered by tests, IMHO.  Also, it makes it easier to provide alternate views, for example, if you want both a GUI and a CLI.  But, read the article, it covers the topic well.

Comment: Mediator pattern MVC doesn't have a connection between M and V