# What is the difference between MVC and MVP

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, design-patterns, mvp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are MVP and MVC and what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference)

I know MVC (Model-View-Controller). Can somebody precisely reason how MVP is different from MVC?
Also Where is MVP desirable than MVC?

Comment: Hover the tags "MVC" and then "MVP".

Comment: [Many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733700/what-is-the-difference-between-controller-in-mvc-pattern-and-presenter-in-mvp-pat), [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219056/what-is-the-difference-between-mvp-and-mvc), [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860470/mvp-vs-mvc) dupes for this.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference) appears to be the most comprehensive dupe.

Comment: @cnicutar @razlebe Thanks for pointing out, I understand what SO expects. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MVP the view is not allowed to "think". The presenter contains all the logic.

look at this: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html#presenter