# Difference between MVC & MVP architecture

Tags: c#, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are MVP and MVC and what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference)

i am not aware of MVC & MVP coding design flow. i need to understand what is difference in terms of coding. i search google but found no expected article on it. i need explanation with sample code for both MVC & MVP. i need small sample code where same thing will be done via both MVP & MVC for win application with c#. so please anyone help me out with a good sample.

Answer (score 0):

Download the ASP.NET MVC project and the ASP.NET Web Forms MVP. They are available at codeplex.com. But remember they are one way to implement/apply the patern (theory) in code. There is no "unique" way to implement those patterns. Ruby on Rails has it's own implementation of the MVC pattern.

Comment: plzz give me actual url if u know for downloading ASP.NET MVC project and the ASP.NET Web Forms MVP both from codeplex.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/03/21/asp-net-mvc-source-code-now-available.aspx

Comment: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781

Comment: and finally the ASP.NET MVP: http://webformsmvp.codeplex.com/