# Is MVC and MVP supervising controller the same?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, architecture, mvp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are MVP and MVC and what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference)

I have read the following description for the MVC in a website:

> In this case of MVC the Controller simply builds the Model and passes
>   it off to the View for rendering.  No stateful interplay between the
>   View and Controller, just a “hey, here’s the Model, see you later”
>   from the Controller to the View.

I have read the following about the MVP - Supervising controller

> Supervising Controller: The Presenter handles user gestures. The View
>   binds to the Model directly through data binding. In this case it's
>   the Presenter's job to pass off the Model to the View so that it can
>   bind to it. The Presenter will also contain logic for gestures like
>   pressing a button, navigation, etc.

From the description above i feel like the underlying logic behind  MVC and MVP - supervising controller are same.

Is my understanding correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great post already on Stackoverflow addressing this question in [What are MVP and MVC and what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: This should be posted as a comment (and vote-to-close), not an answer.

Comment: @outis I think this question is readly different from the question in possible duplicate. Can I repeat this question????