# GWT MVP History vs Events

Tags: gwt, mvp, gwt-history

In GWT app where one has multiple presenters rendering views based on user actions/events, I have certain questions wrt MVP

1) What is the best way to pass data between multiple presenters. For example one presenter needs to pass a String or any other Object to other presenter. Of course the method should be such that presenters are still decoupled

2) For navigation around multiple presenters/views should one use Events or History or Both? Is there any specific drawback of using only History tokens and not having events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing complex information between `presenters` is done best via `events`.
However I wouldn't completely neglect `History`. 
If you want to support **bookmarks** and allow the user to load/go back to a specific application state/view you have to use History.

You might use a hybrid approach between Activity/Places and Custom Events.

- Parse the history token (Activity/Places)
- Load the application state/information based on the history token
- Use events to update the various presenters/views

Answer (score 1):

MVC is not really simple to use with GWT. The best practice for GWT is the MVP model. There is a very good presentation from Google I/O 2009 at [google-code](http://www.google.com/intl/de-DE/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html).

And there is a really [good tutorial for MVP](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html) with GWT.

The difference between MVP and MVC is explained very detailed [here at stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference).

Sorry not to answer your question directly - but I think your problem comes by using an unfitting design-pattern. IMHO with the MVP-pattern the question will be solved.

Comment: Oops..I meant to type MVP, but some background lens made me write MVC. so I am using exactly same design pattern as suggested in your article and it's working very well. The only difficulty I am having is in passing data between presenters, and only that part is clumsy. Rest I got quite clean!

Comment: After going through article again today, I feel I made a wrong choice when I banked on History instead of events. Events carry the data very well, I probably didn't realize their usefulness in beginning, but now I can see it!

Comment: Best practice is passing Objects instead of Strings. Events usually carry any Object. If you use History only, you need to pass everything as String. IMHO this definitifly is a very "expensive" (means: a lot of work) and unstable way to handle your internal communication.