# Class layout when implementing a GUI with Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mouselistener

So I've made a game in Java, mostly for practice. It works in the command line now, but now I want to implement it in a GUI with Swing. I got some pictures etc. to implement, but that's not relevant now. I also want to implement a mouselistener.

My (basic) question is: how should I do the layout of the classes? I got my game main class, and some subclasses. Should I create a seperate class for the GUI, or should I just implement it in my game main class? Also, where does the mouse listener go?

Sorry for the newbie question, I'm a beginner with GUI's and I want to do it right.

Comment: Side note: Since this is a new GUI project consider JavaFX instead of Swing. Swing is currently in maintenance mode and Oracle plans JavaFX to be its successor.

Comment: Your question is very broad and can best be answered at this stage by referring you to the Swing tutorials, which you can find here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info). In particular, look up the layout manager tutorials and give them a go. Your best bet is to use this site after you've tried to create something.

Comment: You may get some ideas form the [_package-private_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) classes in this simple [game](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Answer (score -2):

You might try to use a  Model View Presenter pattern, as described here:

[I've been taught not to place most methods in a general "System" class but where do they go instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613979/ive-been-taught-not-to-place-most-methods-in-a-general-system-class-but-where/28616621#28616621)

Comment: The OP specifically asks about Swing and you answer that he should use JavaFX. This kind of answers is good for the comments, not for an answer.