# Searching for an example of class-binding by a interface

Tags: java, interface, mvp

I am trying try to implement a MVP-Pattern example in Java 
but I do not know how the interface connection between the Presenter and the View works! Does someone know a good example of this?

More details:
In some sources a class diagram looks like this [diagram](https://sites.google.com/site/akstechtalks/tech-topics/Architecture/patterns/architectural-patterns/presentation-patterns/web-presentation-patterns/model-view-presenter-mvp-pattern)

The arrow between the Presenter and the View is interrupted by a ball. This is the symbol of a interface, right?

The Presenter knows the View and the View knows the Presenter, so both need references to each other. For testing I don't want to write `new ..();` in the constructor.

If I set the View- and the Presentor- reference by constructor it looks like
this:

```
CentralView myView = new CentralView(myPresenter);
CenterPresenter myPresenter = new CenterPresenter(myView);
```

I would appreciate an example of how this works, without "new" in constructor, to be testable and without getter and setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this easiest:

```
 Model model = new Model();
 View view = new View();
 Presenter presenter = new Presenter(model, view);
 view.setPresenter(presenter);
```

However, if you insist on "no setters", you should really look up on dependency injection. For example, using [guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Motivation):

```
 // can resolve dependencies by itself
 Presenter presenter = new Presenter();

 // Dependency injection hard at work within your constructor
 @Inject
 Presenter(Model model, View view) {
      this.model = model;
      this.view = view;
 }
```

Dependency injection can be used both to replace factories and to resolve circular dependencies (guice uses "proxies" for that).

Answer (score 0):

i founded an example, to my question, here:
[MVP-Example with interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367250/concrete-code-example-of-mvp)
It use setter and getter, but it explain how it works with interfaces.

Bye :-)