# What is the best way for managing data between classes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, list

using c# - WinForms, .net Framework 4.5, VS 2012

Try to create small app with some entity.
I create separate class for my entity and put some simple code inside:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Color {get; set;}
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string CarModel { get; set; }
}
```

Then from main form i create some specimen of class `Car` (creating can be geted by clicking button from main form, after clicking new form with 3 text boxes will be opened, if information entered and button Ok clicked - new `Car` sample must be created and returned to main form).

For this i try to use next code:

```
    public Car myCar = new Car();
    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myCar.Color = textBoxColor.Text;
        myCar.Make = textBoxMake.Text;
        myCar.CarModel = textBoxModel.Text;
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Added");
        this.Close();
    }
```

For moving data from new form to main form I use public field `public Car myCar = new Car();`, but this is not the best way to do this, due to using of `public` field.

Another way I found - in main form create next method

```
    static List<Car> carInStock = null;
    public static void myCar(string color, string make, string model)
    {
        Car myCar = new Car
        {
            Color = color,
            CarModel = model,
            Make = make
        };
        MainForm.carInStock.Add(myNewCar);
    }
```

and for button can use method like:

```
    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainForm.myCar(textBoxColor.Text,
        textBoxMake.Text,
        textBoxModel.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Added");
        this.Close();
    }
```

But think varian also not hte best and prefered.

**Question**: What is the best way to move created entity (in this case entity of `Car`, represented as `myCar`) from one form to another?

Comment: Please define "best". Most readable? Quick? Memory efficient?

Comment: Probably a car repository. Look up dependency injection.

Comment: Means under "best" most protected way and quick

Comment: I'd say you want a standard factory pattern see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern  *there are also patterns when you only want concrete types.

Comment: `standard factory pattern`- never hear abot this - need to read about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of GUI Application, I suggest you follow MVC or MVP pattern.  The class car is the model, the Windows Forms are the views, the view doesn't hold an instance of the model, and the views are updated through controller or presenter.

You can find  more details about MVC/MVP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: if be honesty - never read about `patterns` (as i wrote abowe), but looks like it's very usefull stuff

Comment: Please learn MVP - it will make your WinForms life much easier. :)

Comment: @Matt - really interesting and helpfull link