# How to create CSV Address field with commas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a model Company, this model has a field Address.
`Company.first.address` returns the following in the console:

```
"11 Local Street,\r\n" + "City,\r\n" + "POSTCODE"
```

This throws a spanner in the works when I try to export using

```
CSV.generate_line([company.name, company.address])
```

The address field spans more than one column and therefore makes the CSV not useful.

Can't seem to find a way to turn it into a single quoted string.

This is the full create.csv.erb:

```
<%- headers = [
              'name',
              'email',
              'address',
              'phone',
              'contract_date',
              'deal_percentage',
              'active',
              'editable'
              ] -%>
<%= (CSV.generate_line(headers)).strip %>
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
  <%= CSV.generate_line([
                        company.name,
                        company.email,
                        company.address,
                        company.phone,
                        company.contract_date,
                        company.deal_percentage,
                        company.active,
                        company.editable
    ], { quote_char: "\0", encoding: "UTF-8" }).strip %>
<% end %>
```

I'm using Ruby 2.4.0 and Rails 5.0.1.

Comment: Can you post the exact code you're using?

Comment: This has nothing to do with commas. CSV values can contain commas and newlines, and `CSV` has no trouble automatically escaping them: `CSV.generate_line(['foo', 'foo,bar', "foo,\nbar"]) # => "foo,\"foo,bar\",\"foo,\nbar\"\n"`

Comment: Why are you using `"\0"` as your quote character? You're explicitly telling `CSV` to use `"\0"` to quote cells that contain commas.

Comment: When I remove the quote_char I get the same problem.

Also this is giving me the + too

2.4.0 (main):0 > CSV.generate_line(['foo', 'foo,bar', "foo,\nbar"])
=> "foo,\"foo,bar\",\"foo,\n" + "bar\"\n"

Is there a way to format the address on the model level, I am fine with over-riding it.

Comment: You shouldn't be generating the CSV in your view. That logic should be in your controller, where you assign the output to a variable, then access the variable in your view.

Comment: @theTinMan could you point me in the direction of some more info about this please, can't seem to find any references where the CSV rows are actually generated in the controller. I see some where the model is used with a custom `to_csv` method, is this expected to deal with the address field differently than in the view?

Comment: Rails is an [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/a/101561/128421) system. The logic in a view should be simple conditional tests to determine what variables to display and to loop over arrays or hashes. The creation of those variables is done in the controller to keep the view clean. The [CSV documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) shows how to output to a string among other methods of generating output. You should be able to figure it out from that. The Rails tutorials go into this too.