# What is the major difference between MVC,MVP,MVVC and VIPER pattern in android with example?

Tags: design-patterns

Today i want to ask something about **design pattern** , i have studies many posts but none of them explains clearly ,**Can anyone helps me to explaning me the difference of all these patterns** with any simple example like creating a **simple login page with two input fields and a button ,when pressing the button hits the url and get response**

Thank in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are MVP and MVC and what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference)