# MVC or MVP for location tracking and alert android application

Tags: android, model-view-controller, mobile, mvp

I am creating a simple personal safety application for students at a University. However having spent several hours researching design patterns, I am still struggling to work out whether MVC or MVP would be better. I understand that MVP allows for better unit testing etc.

However would MVC be enough for this type of application or am I better off going with MVP?

The main features are:

- Users will be able to raise emergency alerts and the application would send the users location to the campus security.
- The user can also make calls to university services through the    application
- The user will be able to find the  nearest bus.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go with MVP, as it's more common on android and you can find more resources for it (articles, blog posts, examples, stack overflow questions).

Here's one you can get started with:

- [Model-View-Presenter: Android guidelines](https://medium.com/@cervonefrancesco/model-view-presenter-android-guidelines-94970b430ddf)

Also, check out this answer on stackoverflow: [What are MVP and MVC and what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference?rq=1).